# Sysprep vs cloning or a mixture of the two?

Tags: windows-7, clone, sysprep

I have fifty computers (not the same) and the boss wants a new identical Windows 7 image on all of them. Unfortunately it's not just a Windows 7 / Office 2010 image but one with a load of other programs and customisations.

Should I do this using sysprep (which I have never used before) or is there something like XXcopy from my old DOS days? And where are the best tutorials for someone who is still learning this stuff?

Comment: See [What is sysprep? how is it useful?](http://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful) and [Looking for a software capable of cloning a System drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/61317/looking-for-a-software-capable-of-cloning-a-system-drive). But in reality, this is a question for ServerFault (and has been asked many times over there), so I'm voting to migrate it there.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT). It will let you take an original Windows 7 image (from the DVD) and customize it with drivers and applications. Drivers are injected on the fly if the given hardware needs them. Applications can be installed always or based on custom rules (only if the PC is xyz model, for example).

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/349424/creating-windows-7-images-in-audit-mode is my question about it. You need to make sure you GENERALIZE though before you enter OOBE state. That will remove the Hardware IDs, and act like a generic system the next time you boot up